# Can i extract specific information in serialized array in db or is there a better way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying to get the data out from a serialized array in a "text" column in the database. I hope to do something better than having the use a serialized array in a text column as i had read around the internet that it is hard to get the exact data in the array from a serialized YAML data in text column in DB using this code:

```
  def create
        @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
        @shopping_cart.add(@product, @product.price)
        redirect_to new_simcard_path
  end

  def checkout
    @order = Order.new
    @order.total = @shopping_cart.total
    @order.sub_total = @shopping_cart.subtotal
    @order.sales_tax = @shopping_cart.taxes
    @order.shopping_cart_id = @shopping_cart.id
    @order.products = []
    @shopping_cart.shopping_cart_items.each do |cart_item|
        @order.products << cart_item.item.name
        @order.products << cart_item.quantity
    end 
  end
```

"products" is essentially the abovementioned "text" column and each and every item is added to this "text" column in a form of an array. However, if i were to have to only try to extract only "cart_item.item.name" it would be hard as the data is serialized in the array.

Is there a better way to solve this problem? I hope to avoid using serialized arrays in the DB like the above.

** EDIT **

Just to explain that i was using acts_as_shopping_cart gem and adding the product is already included in the gem's feature. (adding the part where the product is added to cart)

Comment: Is there a need in storing the products data in the order table?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you created a new model, `Product` with a `has_many :through` association to order. [doc](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :product_orders
  has_many :orders, through: :product_orders

end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :product_orders
  has_many :products, through: :product_orders
end

class ProductOrder < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :product

  # attributes
  # price, VAT, quantity, etc
end
```

and apply the relevant migrations.

This way you will be able to implement each cart_item as a relation between orders and products, and keep all the volatile attributes (purchase_price, VAT, discount, quantity) in the intermediate model `ProductOrder`.

KISS example:

```
@shopping_cart.shopping_cart_items.each do |cart_item|
  product_order = @order.products.create(product: cart_item.to_product)
  product_order.name = cart_item.item.name
  product_order.quantity = cart_item.quantity
  product_order.save
  # ...
end
```

will give you `@order.products` as expected.

Comment: How do i relate the cart_item when this is done? I had "has_and_belongs_to_many :orders" in my Product model. Now i have errors with that after changing the the relaton you mentioned?

Comment: check the doc. You need to create a proper migration for this to work.

Comment: Yeap. i did the migration and added "name" and "quantity" (even "product_id" and "order_id") to product_order model. The "to_product" is a little ambiguous for me unlike to_s, to_a (for strings and array)

Comment: `to_product` is an example method to show that you need to provide a product to the relation.

Comment: I couldn't as the product is added to a "cart" via posting the product_id to a 'create' action in the cart and adding the details (like name and price) - i have updated the code above, as i know your idea was not specific to using a gem which i was using (acts_as_shopping_cart)